# Apache Expire header when url has parameter

Tags: apache-2.4

I want to serve some files using an expire header with one year. These files will have a cache parameter in its urls.

I tried the following configuration, but it is not working.

`<FilesMatch "\?cache=">`
     `<ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year">`
`</FilesMatch>`

Does anyone know how can I apply this header only when the request file have this cache parameter? I am using Apache 2.4.7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FilesMatch will only match the file and not any parameter.

One way that might work (untested) would be to use [SetEnvIf](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) to set an environment variable and then use that variable in an [If statement](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if). Potentially you might even be able to do this directly using If and not SetEnvIf

More info on using env variables in Apache: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/env.html